# Software chorded keyboard for OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm looking for some kind of software that will allow me to use a chorded keyboard layout, similar to [tiptap.mobi](http://tiptap.mobi/) on OS X. Ideally the closer this is to a normal keyboard layout the better.

I've considered ukelele, but it appears to only allow me to map a single key to a single output.

Comment: What do you plan to use for the keyboard?  Most standard keyboards (due to their electrical design) do not allow chording except for certain key combinations.

Comment: Typing, primarily. I'd be willing to use hotspots on my trackpad.

Comment: How many simultaneous touches does your trackpad support?

Comment: It's the built in Macbook Pro trackpad, so not sure yet :/

Comment: I'm guessing no more than 2-3.  But I would think there would be a utility that would show you the touch points.

Comment: Any idea what that utility would be?

Comment: No idea as to the utility -- I'd think it would come with your touch pad.  But someone else here had the idea of using a piano-style keyboard for chording.  It would output MIDI, which is fairly easy to handle in a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check http://openstenoproject.org/ . I try to install it on Mavericks without success, but the chord typing works http://stenoknight.com/kws.html

Answer (score 0):

After more digging around, my friend showed me this: http://www.frogpad.com/magic-frogpad.php

Which seems to be what I want. I'll report back later.

Edit: Screw that! $130 for the software? No thanks.

Comment: You're in the US, just get the version that comes with a free Magic Trackpad (69$ usually). Also, it's not like they have a huge market of prospective buyers. Making software for just a handful of people means they must pay a larger share of the cost...

Answer (score 0):

Try Karabiner: https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en

I've used it for years. It includes a predefined chorded layout (asetniop) but you can also create your own via an xml configuration file.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. Provide more than just a link, ie some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.